# How to apply a filter in opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am attempting to apply a sepia tone filter to an image using OpenCV and C++. However, the result is not as expected, and the image is turning almost entirely green. I've included the relevant code below:

```
Mat src = imread("/Users/nithin/Desktop/neu/CV/images/curry.jpeg");

if (src.empty())
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image." << endl;
    return -1;
}

// Create a new Mat to store the sepia-toned image
Mat sepiaToned = src.clone();

// Iterate through each pixel
for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
    {
        Vec3b pixel = src.at<Vec3b>(y, x);

        // Apply sepia tone filter
        float blue = pixel[0];
        float green = pixel[1];
        float red = pixel[2];

        float newR = 0.393 * red + 0.349 * green + 0.272 * blue;
        float newG = 0.769 * red + 0.686 * green + 0.534 * blue;
        float newB = 0.189 * red + 0.168 * green + 0.131 * blue;

        // Update pixel values in the new Mat
        sepiaToned.at<Vec3b>(y, x) = Vec3b(static_cast<uchar>(newB), static_cast<uchar>(newG), static_cast<uchar>(newR));
    }
}

// Display the original and sepia-toned images
imshow("Original Image", src);
imshow("Sepia-Toned Image", sepiaToned);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

I would like to know why isn't the filter applying, it is turning the image almost green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pixel overflow.** Your calculations produce pixel intensities outside of the valid range `[0, 255]` resulting in *wrap around*. You should keep your values within the valid range and then casting to the proper type (`uchar`, in this case).

Use [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) functions provided by OpenCV: [`cv::saturate_cast<>`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab93126370b85fda2c8bfaf8c811faeaf). Also, your conversion to sepia seems to be wrong. I used the weights from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061093/how-is-a-sepia-tone-created). The updated code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{

    // Read image:
    std::string imagePath = "D://opencvImages//swedishsnoop.png";
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread(imagePath, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Create a new Mat to store the sepia-toned image
    cv::Mat sepiaToned = inputImage.clone();

    // Iterate through each pixel
    for (int y = 0; y < inputImage.rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < inputImage.cols; x++)
        {
            cv::Vec3b pixel = inputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);

            // Apply sepia tone filter
            float blue = pixel[0];
            float green = pixel[1];
            float red = pixel[2];

            float newR = (0.393 * red) + (0.769 * green) + (0.189 * blue);
            float newG = (0.349 * red) + (0.686 * green) + (0.168 * blue);
            float newB = (0.272 * red) + (0.534 * green) + (0.131 * blue);

            // Properly saturate cast pixel intensities:
            newB = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(newB);
            newG = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(newG);
            newR = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(newR);

            // Update pixel values in the new Mat
            sepiaToned.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = cv::Vec3b(newB, newG, newR);
        }
    }

    // Display the original and sepia-toned images
    cv::imshow("Original Image", inputImage);
    cv::imshow("Sepia-Toned Image", sepiaToned);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;

}
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]